# Xamarin carplay supported ios app crashes when starting

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, carplay

Our app crashes as soon as it is launched after carplay integration. if i install directly (from ipa) it works. But if I install from testflight it crashes. If you remove

```
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
<key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
<dict>
<key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
<true/>
<key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>UISceneClassName</key>
<string>UIWindowScene</string>
<key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
<string>__ABC_DEFAULT_SCENE_CONFIGURATION__</string>
<key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
<string>DeviceSceneDelegate</string>
</dict>
</array>
<key>CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>UISceneClassName</key>
<string>CPTemplateApplicationScene</string>
<key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
<string>ABC-Car</string>
<key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
<string>CarPlaySceneDelegateABC</string>
</dict>
</array>
</dict>
</dict>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>ABC</string>
```

from Info.plist problem is solved but carplay is disabled.

I tried delete this code below and problem is solved but carplay disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is something wrong in your Info.plist. The [example code in the official document about the iPadOS and macOS configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/windows#ipados-and-macos-configuration) is:

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
  <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
  <true/>
  <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
  <dict>
    <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
        <string>__MAUI_DEFAULT_SCENE_CONFIGURATION__</string>
        <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
        <string>SceneDelegate</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

You put the `UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes` in wrong place. It should be out of the `UISceneConfigurations` key.